# Variance of absolute value sums of random variables

Tags: probability

Let $X=\left|\sum _{i=1}^n Z_{i} \right|$ and $Y=\sum _{i=1}^n |Z_{i} |$ where random variables $(\textit{Z${}_{i}$})$ are i.i.d, and

$Z_{i} =0$,$+1$ or$-1$, with probability ${p}{}_{0}$, ${p}{}_{1}$, ${p}{}_{-1}$ respectively s.t. $p_0+p_1+p_{-1}=1$.

What is ${Var}({X})$ and ${Var}({Y})$?

PS: What I'm actually missing here is ${E}({X})$.

Thanks!

Comment: Well, var$(Y)$ should be easy. What have you tried thus far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Yes, $Var(Y)$ is easy, but what about $Var(X)$...?

Comment: Finding $\mathbb EX^2$ should be easy too. So the essential question seems to be: what is $\mathbb EX$? Do you agree with that?

Comment: Yes, I agree.... and?

Comment: Well, then why don't you just restrict to asking this essential question (and add your own efforts)? Advice for nicer notation: use probabilities indexed with $0,1,-1$ in the understanding that they satisfy $p_{0}+p_{-1}+p_{1}=1$. As you can see at the moment I am only commenting, not answering. As you will understand I can only give you an answer if I have one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but I can only find a (not very nice) expression for $\mathbb EX$

For $j\in\{-1,0,1\}$ let $N_j$ denote the cardinality of set of indices $i$ with $Z_i=j$.

Then $N_{-1}+N_1+N_0=n$ and for nonnegative integers $k_j$ with $k_{-1}+k_1+k_0=n$ we have:

$$P(N_{-1}=k_{-1}\wedge N_1=k_1)=\frac{n!}{k_{-1}!k_1!k_0!}p_{-1}^{k_{-1}}p_1^{k_1}p_0^{k_0}$$

Next to that we have $X=|N_1-N_{-1}|$ so we end up with the expression:
$$\mathbb EX=\mathbb E|N_1-N_{-1}|=\sum_{k_{_{-1}}+k_{1}+k_0=n}|k_1-k_{-1}|\frac{n!}{k_{-1}!k_1!k_0!}p_{-1}^{k_{-1}}p_1^{k_1}p_0^{k_0}$$

I hope that someone can do better.

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is that since my $n$ is very large (the problem is from a genetics model), the sum ($O(n^2)$) and factorials make it somewhat intractable.